# No response after authentication success in pentaho?

Tags: authentication, redirect, pentaho

I try to use Basic Authentication to make a login into Pentaho by using .NET code

My code is:

```
Dim request = WebRequest.Create("http://x.x.x.x:8080/pentaho/Home")
Dim authInfo As String = Convert.ToString(userName) & ":" & Convert.ToString(userPassword)
authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.[Default].GetBytes(authInfo))
request.Headers("Authorization") = "Basic " & authInfo
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
```

You can see that I pass the authorization header with Basic username:password with Base64 encode.

for the last line of above code

```
Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
```

you can see that I get the response from pentaho server then assign to variable **response**

In running, I found that Pentaho can return response and put the value to variable **response**.It seem okay that the authentication is **passed** and I login successfully

but when I input a link `http://x.x.x.x:8080/pentaho/Home`  the login page still prompt and I need to login again....

Do you know what code I missing so that the Pentaho cannot login auto after above code?
Thanks you much!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting it as parameters in the url i.e :

```
?userid=joe&password=password
```

However, looking at it again it seems if you're successfully getting a logged in response, then the next request you are not logged in then you have not preserved the session/cookie between those two requests.  Easily done in java with httpclient, not so sure about .net

Comment: Thank you for your response! yes I knew that I can use parameter in url for login authentication, but it is not secure method....   do you have a sample code of java? I want to have a reference as well. Thanks again!

Comment: yeah I know it's not secure but I was just curious to know if it worked or not?  Also; One more thing. When you say it logs in successfully how do you know? did you check the response content?  not just the status code? There are occasions where the BI server returns errors in the page text, but also 200 OK!  I dont have any httpclient reference code, but just google for httpclient and cookies/sessions etc.

Comment: Thanks Codek!  I have checked the response content, the content is a whole html source code returned like `<html><script>...</script>...<body>...</body>...</html>`   the status code is 200 OK   I used a `streamreader` and `reader.readtoend()` to get the response content. so I think the authentication is passed but it is strange that the login page still prompt...